# Why is rebar ignoring my ct_dir setting?

Tags: rebar

I've got an Erlang program arranged like this:

```
deps/
apps/
apps/foo/
apps/foo/src/
```

...etc.

My top-level `rebar.config` contains a `ct_dir` option, as follows:

```
{ct_dir, "suites"}.
```

...but `./rebar ct` is still looking for suite files in the `test` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The `ct_dir` (and `ct_log_dir`) settings are **local**. This means that they must be specified in a per-application `rebar.config` file.

Create `apps/foo/rebar.config` and put the `ct_dir` option in there.