# Reason: undef while running common tests in erl console [Erlang]

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, common-test

I have running application and in the interactive console I try to run common test suites located in test/common directory:

```
ct:run("test/common").
```

But I get a bunch of errors:

```
Reason: undef
```

and all tests fail.
I tried to run them from linux shell

```
ct_run -dir test/common
```

or like this:

```
ct_run -boot start_sasl -spec test/common/app_ct.spec -erl_args -config env/dev.config
```

with the same result.

But when I run them using rebar (the second version, not rebar3)

```
rebar ct
```

Everything works, tests pass. But it takes too much time to compile the app and to start it.

In the rebar.config I have:

```
{ct_dir,"test/common"}.
{ct_log_dir,"test/logs"}.
{ct_extra_params,"-boot start_sasl -pa deps/*/ebin -pa ebin -spec test/common/app_ct.spec -erl_args -config env/dev.config"}.
```

and in the test/common/app_ct.spec I have:

```
{verbosity, 100}.
{init, {eval, [{application, ensure_all_started, [app]}, {timer, sleep, [30000]}]}}.
{alias, common, "./test/common/"}.
{suites, "", [app_srv_SUITE, app_client_SUITE]}.
```

**What can I do to run tests from erl console using ct:run("test/common")?**

My goal is to be able to recompile single test files individually and run tests from working application console without stopping and recompiling all application.

I recompile singular test module without problems like this:

```
c("test/common/new_mod_SUITE.erl", [{i, "include"}, {i, "deps"}, {outdir, "test/common"}]).
```

But I still can't run tests after that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, need to be sure that all tests is compiled and they are inside of folder what is put as argument into [ct:run/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#run-1). If need to run only one test from specific folder, can be used [ct:run/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#run-2). If need to run specific test case from specific folder, can be used specific folder [ct:run/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#run-3). Examples:

```erlang
1> ct:run("test/common").
2> ct:run("test/common", "some_SUITE").
```

However I would recommend using [rebar3](https://rebar3.readme.io/docs/running-tests), in `rebar3` was added option like `--dir` and tests from specific folder can be run like:

```sh
$ ./rebar3 ct --dir="test/common"
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked and .beam files are in place in the specified directory, I can compile them to that directory with no problems like this: c("test/common/new_mod_SUITE.erl", [{i, "include"}, {i, "deps"}, {outdir, "test/common"}]). But when I try to run tests ct:run("test/common", "new_mod_SUITE"). I still get error Reason: undef.

Comment: By the way, after I compile the SUITE module, I can call all test cases from it in the erlang terminal one by one by hands but it's too tedious and takes too much time.

Comment: You see, the Erlang modules must be compiled, please see documentation - https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/code_loading.html. If you will try use `rebar3` as I wrote above, you will be able to run tests in specific folder eg: `rebar3 ct --dir="test/common"`. But no matter whether you want to run manually or using tools - all modules must be compiled before call or run common tests.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding, obviously I wasn't clear enough. What I'm really trying to say is that I compile and recompile my test suite with no problems from erlang console, opened after I had started the application. And in that console I can call my test cases manually like my_SUITE:first_test_case(). What I can't get working is being able to call ct:run("test/common", "my_SUITE"). from the erlang console because when I run this command I get Reason: undef error and I have no clue what I'm missing. But it has nothing to do with rebar version.

Comment: The error appears after my_SUITE module is compiled. The .beam file is in place, I checked. Without compiled module I wouldn't be able to run test cases from the module manually. My guess is the Reason: undef error stems from some missing step needed to be done before calling ct:run() command (may be start ct application or call some function before running ct:run()). It's just the error itself is not very informative for me.

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't help, but here is what happens for me using `rebar3`:

```
~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp$ ls
LICENSE     _build      rebar.lock  test
README.md   rebar.config    src

~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp$ cd src
~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/src$ ls
a.erl       myapp_app.erl   rebar.lock
myapp.app.src   myapp_sup.erl

~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/src$ cat a.erl
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).
%%-include("eunit.hrl").


hello() -> io:format("hello").

~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/src$ cd ../test
~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/test$ ls
a_SUITE.erl

~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/test$ cat a_SUITE.erl 
-module(a_SUITE).
-compile(export_all).

all() -> [go].

go(_Config) ->
   1 = 1. 

~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/test$ cd ..
~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp$ rebar3 compile
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling myapp
~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp$ rebar3 shell
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling myapp
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)
1> ===> The rebar3 shell is a development tool; to deploy applications in production, consider using releases (http://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases)
===> Booted myapp
 
1> ct:run("test").

Common Test: Running make in test directories...
Recompile: a_SUITE
a_SUITE.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

CWD set to: "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/ct_run.nonode@nohost.2021-02-14_14.26.08"

TEST INFO: 1 test(s), 1 case(s) in 1 suite(s)

Testing myrebar.myapp: Starting test, 1 test cases
Testing myrebar.myapp: TEST COMPLETE, 1 ok, 0 failed of 1 test cases

Updating /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/index.html ... done
Updating /Users/7stud/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp/all_runs.html ... done
{1,0,{0,0}}
2>
```

Then after exiting the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp$ 

~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp$ rebar3 ct
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling myapp
test/a_SUITE.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

===> Running Common Test suites...
%%% a_SUITE: .
All 1 tests passed.

~/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp$
```

I didn't touch rebar.config, it is the default produced by rebar3:

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{deps, [{eleveldb, "2.2.20"}]
}.

{shell, [
  % {config, "config/sys.config"},
    {apps, [myapp]}
]}.
```

I would try printing your current working directory when you are in the shell:

```
2> pwd().
/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/myrebar/myapp
ok
```

Then try using either a full path or a relative path from that directory, e.g.:

```
"./test/common"
"Users/../../test/common"
```

Then, I would move all your `*_SUITE.erl` files except one into a directory outside your app, and just work with one test file.  Then, I would get rid of all that config file stuff and try again.

Comment: I've checked pwd(). and it gave me the root directory of the project /home/andr/projects/my_proj. Tried to run tests both ways ct:run("./test/common") and ct:run("/home/andr/projects/my_proj/test/common"). The error Reason: undef still persists, Tests fail.

Comment: @AndreyKo, Okay, now try getting rid of the rebar.config stuff.

Comment: @AndreyKo, After that, I would try creating a whole new application with just one test file, and see if you can get that test to run.  Or, just use your current application and move all the src files out of the src directory and move all the test files out of the test directory, and see if you can get one test placed in the "./test" directory to run.  Is `ct_dir` relative to the test dir, so that you should be specifying "common"?

Comment: @AndreyKo, Some info here: https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/issues/415

Comment: @AndreyKo, More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265672/why-is-rebar-ignoring-my-ct-dir-setting